# is it possible to configure one Presto instance to act as both coordinator and worker

Tags: presto

I have installed presto server from this repo
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prestosql/presto-server/330/

Then downloaded
apache-hive-3.1.3-bin
and
hadoop-3.3.3
Then initialized hive metastore and launched presto-server by bin/launcher run
Then launched presto-cli by

```
`./presto-cli --server 127.0.0.1:8080 --catalog hive --schema default`
```

In which i'm trying to create a schema:

```
`presto:default> create schema hive.mytest with (location = 's3a://my-bucket/mytest');`
```

and have very unclear output

```
`Query 20220828_084647_00002_rnxa4 failed: localhost:9083`
```

In server stderr i see this:

```
io.prestosql.NotInTransactionException: Unknown transaction ID: eadd5d61-4524-4b9e-9ade-6596089b0712. Possibly expired? Commands ignored until end of transaction block
    ....
```

These are my presto **config.properties**

```
    coordinator=true
    node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
    http-server.http.port=8080
    query.max-memory=5GB
    query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
    query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
    discovery-server.enabled=true
    discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

**node.properties**

```
    node.environment=demo
    inode.data-dir=/home/patrick/presto-server-330/var/data
```

and **hive.properties**

```
    connector.name=hive-hadoop2
        hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
        hive.s3.aws-access-key=**************
        hive.s3.aws-secret-key=***************
```

So... my question is - does presto miss a worker node?
Is it possible to configure one instance as both coordinator and worker?

Where can i see more verbose logs of presto sql statements?

Comment: The problem is your Presto coordinator is unable to communicate with Hive. If you are using EC2 then try opening port 9083? If not debug it by connecting to hive using other sql clients or telnetting to 9083 from same machine or different machine.

Comment: and yes you can always configure your coordinator to be both

Comment: Nope, both hcat_server on 9083 and presto are on the same host and hcat is on 0.0.0.0 )